# Failed release upgrade caused unmet dependencies that broke package system in Ubuntu 16.04+

Tags: ubuntu, console, upgrade, apt-get

I got vps that was running Ubuntu 16.04 and release upgrade caused unmet dependencies all over the system. SSH and FTP services are not working and I'm using "emergency console" that allows me console access.

Mainly major problem is that the package system itself has unmet dependencies and pretty much all command I have tried to google end in box with text: "Kernel must be upgraded. This version of the GNU libc requires kernel version 3.2 or later.  Please upgrade your kernel before installing glibc." And the kernel/release update/upgrade command ends in same box.

I have tried `-f`, `--fix-broken` with `update`, `upgrade`, `do-release-upgrade`
All of these and few other commands (cant remember, tried so many) error something libv6.

For example, running `sudo apt-get upgrade` (error below) I get this and with `-f` or `--fix-broken` I get "kernel must be upgraded" box. (mentioned above)

```
root@3b22:~# apt-get upgrade                                                                                                                                                                                       
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                                                      
Building dependency tree                                                                                                                                                                                           
Reading state information... Done                                                                                                                                                                                  
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.                                                                                                                                                       
The following packages have unmet dependencies:                                                                                                                                                                    
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (> 2.24) but 2.23-0ubuntu11.3 is installed                                                                                                                                              
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (> 2.27) but 2.23-0ubuntu11.3 is installed                                                                                                                                          
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.4) but 2.23-0ubuntu11.3 is installed                                                                                                                                  
 libgssapi-krb5-2 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27) but 2.23-0ubuntu11.3 is installed                                                                                                                                     
 locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.27) but 2.24-11+deb9u4 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.                                                                                                                                                                               
root@3b22:~#
```

My main goal is to restore FTP and if possible SSH connections.

Comment: Would it be easier to create a new server and move your app/systems onto that?